# Deployement Error in Tomcat 6.0 using Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I overwrote the project directory in workspace with a different name and since then have been seeing Document base  is not a readable directory in Netbeans while deploying the application in Tomcat 6.0 . Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not already tried, you can undeploy the problematic application (like FirstWebApplication) if they still show up in the list of webapps.

Comment: Aha Moment, Works well! This was my first attempt at Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

In your server.xml file you will find a line like this:

`Context docBase="yourProject" path="path/to/yourProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:yourProject"/>`

If you just overwrote the project with a diferent name you'll need to make this file consistent with your project new name and location.

Regards.
JHurtado